# jquery how can i make one click do more than one thing , like is there a break function or anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want when I click at the right arrow the next image slide over , and then when I click again the third image
can anyone help me

```
<div class="slider-container carousel-inner">
    <div class="bg-1">
      <img src="images/bg_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-2">
      <img src="images/bg_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-3">
      <img src="images/bg_3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div> 
<!--Css here--!>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".carousel-arrow-next").click(function()){
          $(".bg-2").addClass("slide");
        })
        $(".carousel-arrow-next").click(function(){
            $(".bg-3").addClass("slide-2");
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: You could count how many times the button was clicked with a variable, then perform what you want with such variable.

Comment: Why not use `hide()` and `show()` which are built into the jQuery library. You may also consider adding the HTML and other relevant class identifiers in your question to assist others who may be willing to assist.

Comment: that's a great idea , would you give me hint of how should it be , please?

Comment: its a carousel so i need it to slide

Comment: ok i added the html

Comment: If you are open to using a library, this can be done easily using bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/

Comment: i tried that one , had some issue and then i didnt want to make it like that i wanted to understand how was it made , i mean ..with jquery

Comment: so the first comment was very helpful but there is an issue , the slider ends at the third photo so i want when click on it to get back to the first photo. 
is there reset counter function? or how can i solve it?